# What is the Emergency Shell (emergency.target) of the Systemd, and in what case is it used?

Tags: command-line, systemd

While reading some info about Systemd, I saw there was an 'emergency' Runlevel, linked to 'emergency.target'. Any idea what it is, and when they use it? Merci

Answer (score 4):

Bonjour. The best write up comes from [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Targets.html).

The first step in severe problem resolution is rescue mode initiated with:

```
~]# systemctl rescue

Broadcast message from root@localhost on pts/0 (Fri 2013-10-25 18:23:15 CEST):

The system is going down to rescue mode NOW!
```

However there are times where `rescue mode` doesn't work and you have to enter `emergency` mode. This mounts foot file system as `read-only`, doesn't mount any other local file systems and doesn't enable network connections. To enter emergency mode use:

```
systemctl emergency
```

This is an abbreviated summary so please read the Red Hat link for more detailed `systemd` usage.

All-in-all I think we all hope we never have to use `rescue` target in the first place or `emergency` target second place.

Comment: Is that `mounts foot` or `mounts root`?

Comment: Indeed, I shoudn't have tried it. But, never mind, I managed to co back.